# How to run load tests in seperate appDomain/Process per virtual user

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I'm trying to run a load test on wcf service, and I came across an issue which is getting very frustrating.

We are using [custom credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to authenticate the user identity, and because of this the validation on requests fails for all the users except one, for which the token has been saved.

So we need to:

a) remove the caching of the token, which means every request will have to generate a new token, which could lead to a performance drop, which we would like to avoid during load testing

b) Remove the user validation, which we would also avoid as we don't want to make changes like these to the application that we are testing.

Ideally we would like to be able to run the different user contexts in different application domains which we think would solve our problem. I've came across the similar issue being raised [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5527463b-b8c2-4a28-96d8-4741fd7baab5/how-to-run-load-tests-in-seperate-appdomainprocess-per-virtual-user?forum=vsunittest) with no answer.

Changing the Run Settings -> Run unit tests in application domain to true doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Alright, thats a lot of "I want to do" but what is the actual question?

Comment: um... care to explain the down-vote?

Comment: @IgorMesaros perhaps you are getting downvotes because you are not asking a question not to mention you are not showing any code in regards to what you are currently doing / using not to mention pinpointing the `What, Where, When, How, and Why` things are failing in your existing environment. have you read the [How To Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link.. ?

Comment: I disagree strongly.. all there is to know is there, I edited the title to make sure my question comes across.

Comment: @MethodMan theres a link to msdn to show how we cache the credentials. which is the key point for this problem. What: validation of the request, Where: on the server, When: on request, How: User is not authorised and Why: because there is one token cached for all the users when there should be  individual token for all.